# Where should a IE browser helper object store its data files?

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi, bho

I'm writing a browser helper object for internet explorer that needs to store some data on the hard disk.
Is there a convention, where to store this files? Or if not - to which directory (except the temp folder) do I have write access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally applications store state in [CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA or CSIDL_APPDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but a [low IL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx) process (like [Protected IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) cannot write to those directories, for low IL you can use [FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When running inside the IE process you can use special IE versions of those APIs: [IEGetWriteableFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IEGetWriteableHKCU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537315.aspx)

Comment: IEGetWriteableFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow,&path) does return E_ACCESSDENIED. Is there another folder where I should have write access?

Comment: @Heinzi: Are you in a protected mode IE process? Use IEIsProtectedModeProcess()

Comment: Yes I am, IEIsProtectedModeProcess sets its parameter to true. I'm running IE 8 on a clean install of Windows 7 (without any changes to IE settings)

Answer (score 1):

Create a subdirectory for your app under the path returned by [IEGetWritableFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537314%28VS.85%29.aspx).